# Update MySQL field with a unique value

Tags: mysql, concatenation

I am looking for a mysql update query that will concatenate two fields together and then where unique values still exist add a increment to each value and update a third field. If the concatenated value is unique it should still have to add 1 to the concatenation.

Example

```
Field1   Field2   UniqueValue
======   ======   ===========
A        B        AB1
A        A        AA1
A        A        AA2
A        A        AA3
C        D        CD1
```

Comment: Probably can't be done in a single query. Also, stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: This can be done in a single query, but my feeling is this is bad design.  How do you plan to maintain the unique values when new records are added?

Comment: _I need ..._ Great.

Comment: Do you need a query or an update?

Comment: @RavinderReddy I did put a long description about initially. In the end I read it and decided that it just added confusion and I thought that less was best. Sorry if it appears if impolite but I was trying to be helpful by being clear and concise.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen HI Tim. It is an update that I need. Thanks mate. I will update the question.

Comment: @PrestonDocks Your requirement just invalidated Gurvinder's answer below.  You can't use local variables in a DML update in MySQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use user variable to generate incrementing number per unique combination of the fields and then concatenate them together.

```
select field1, field2, concat(field, rn) UniqueValue
from (
    select
        t.*,
        @rn := if(@field = field, @rn + 1, if(@field := field, 1, 1)) rn
    from
    (select
        field1, field2,
        concat(field1, field2) as field
    from your_table
    order by field
    ) t, (select @rn := 0, @field := null) t2
) t;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/UPZ94787)

If you want to update the table with the generated uniqueValue -

If you have an id column in your table, you could join your table with the above query on that id to do the updates:

```
update your_table t1 join (
select id, concat(field, rn) UniqueValue
from (
    select
        t.id,
        field,
        @rn := if(@field = field, @rn + 1, if(@field := field, 1, 1)) rn
    from
    (select
        id, field1, field2,
        concat(field1, field2) as field
    from your_table
    order by field
    ) t, (select @rn := 0, @field := null) t2
) t
) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
set t1.uniqueValue = t2.UniqueValue;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/XQG41434)

If you don't have an id column, then one way to solve this is using a new table to load the new values and then rename it to the original table:

```
drop table if exists your_table;
drop table if exists your_table_new;
drop table if exists your_table_old;

CREATE TABLE your_table(
   Field1 VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL
  ,Field2 VARCHAR(10)
  ,UniqueValue Varchar(20)
);
INSERT INTO your_table(Field1,Field2) VALUES ('A','B');
INSERT INTO your_table(Field1,Field2) VALUES ('A','A');
INSERT INTO your_table(Field1,Field2) VALUES ('A','A');
INSERT INTO your_table(Field1,Field2) VALUES ('A','A');
INSERT INTO your_table(Field1,Field2) VALUES ('C','D');


create table your_table_new (field1 varchar(10), field2 varchar(10), uniquevalue varchar(20));

insert into your_table_new (field1, field2, uniqueValue)
select field1, field2, concat(field, rn) UniqueValue
from (
    select
        t.*,
        @rn := if(@field = field, @rn + 1, if(@field := field, 1, 1)) rn
    from
    (select
        field1, field2,
        concat(field1, field2) as field
    from your_table
    order by field
    ) t, (select @rn := 0, @field := null) t2
) t;

rename table your_table to your_table_old, your_table_new to your_table;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/WYS11770)

Comment: Initialize `@field` to zero but not `null`. It should be `@field := 0`

Comment: And title of the query says _**Creating ---**_!! your answer just generates a report but not suggesting a way to create or update. Hence will not help much.

Comment: @Ravinder - My understanding of the question is that OP wants to get a unique value based on field1 and field2.

Comment: Appologies, I have not made it fully clear. I have do have a unqiue field that I need to populate with the unique value.

Comment: @PrestonDocks - In that case, let me second Tim's question - How do you plan to maintain the unique values when new records are added? Also, since this is a calculated value, why store it? Would it not be better to use an autoincrement id column instead?

Comment: It's a long story...we warehouse data from multiple erp systems each week. One ERP system does not produce a unqiue value for each line (Don't ask). Once weekly data is pulled we need to pull forecasts that have been updatd by users from the previous week in the current week. For that we need to have a unique id we can link the data with. it's not perfect, but it's the best solution we have. At the moment we use PHP, but it takes about 2 hours to run the weekly update. I am hoping a SQL only solution will only take a matter of minutes.

Comment: @GurV Thanks for the detailed response and various options. I do have an ID Column so I will be able to use that to write the unique value back to the table. Thanks again.